# How to make "upgrade safe" theme for a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, themes, templates, child-theme

I've installed a [*"Cart and Checkout"*](https://whmpress.com/whmcs-cart-order-pages/one-page-checkout/) WP plugin and am trying to make sense of a statement found on the plugin author's website:

> *"Make your own order form template, that upgrades safe and reside in your child theme template following industry standard techniques."*

What *Industry Standard* techniques is he referring to? Can someone point me towards a tutorial on how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

They just mean that you can create your own template for the plugin in a child theme so that the template isn't changed when the plugin is updated. This is both the 'upgrades safe' and 'industry standard' technique being described.

What *specific* file you need to create, and what needs to be in it, is specific to the plugin, and you'll need to ask the author or consult its documentation.

Comment: I've updated my question with a screenshot. So in order the make any "upgrade safe" change, is it as easy as naming the folders and files the same in the plugins folder and editing the newly created files within the theme?

Comment: No. You can’t place aribitrary plugin files in a theme. What this developer is saying is that *they* have a feature where you can replace *some* files in the theme, but - as I said - the specifics about which files and where you put them is something you’ll need to ask the author.

Answer (score 1):

That means in your theme (better to use child theme) you can create the templates for that plugin.

inside your theme create a folder with same name as plugin . then create template folder --> then you create your own templates. 
plugin update won't remove your custom templates.